# The order of looping through an object may be broken only during iteration?

Tags: javascript, object, iteration, for-in-loop

I guess the preferred way of looping through an object is this:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
    console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
  } 
}
```

MDN says that

> **Deleted, added or modified properties**
>   A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an **arbitrary order** (see the delete operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting).

So if I don't modify object properties during iteration I can be guaranteed the correct order i.e. the order in which keys/properties appear in an object or this statement means something else?

Comment: There is no "correct" order. Property order should not be relied upon.

Comment: So there is no way to guarantee the order when looping through an object?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to extract the property names, and then impose your own order by sorting the list (or whatever you want). Properties do not inherently have any ordering.

Comment: "Properties do not inherently have any ordering." ah, that's why. Thank you

Comment: It says "see the delete operator", and if you [follow the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes) it says: "all major browsers support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming first... However, in the case of Internet Explorer (nasty stuff...)"

Comment: @georg Thank you, I stopped at Specifications and thought it was the end of the page, should've scrolled further.

Comment: @MarinaDunst: I added my findings as an answer.

Comment: @Pointy: that's not true anymore for ES6 (unlike ES5), see my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MDN page on delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes) states that:

> ...all major browsers support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming first... However, in the case of Internet Explorer, when one uses delete on a property [and] adds back a property with the same name, the property will be iterated in its old position -- not at the end of the iteration sequence...

Illustration:

```js
var obj = {};

obj.x = 1; 
obj.y = 2;
obj.z = 3;

var a = [];
for(var i in obj) a.push(i);

delete obj.y;
obj.y = 2;

var b = [];
for(var i in obj) b.push(i);


document.write("1:" + a + "<br>2:" + b);
```

Chrome/FF/Safari display `1:x,y,z 2:x,z,y`, while in MSIE (and Edge) the result is `1:x,y,z 2:x,y,z`.

Note that unlike ES5, ES6 mandates that the properties must be iterated in the creation order:

> For each own property key P of O that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order...
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys

The standard is not very clear what exactly "creation order" means. MS takes it that it's the *initial* creation time that matters, while others use the *last* creation time.

Comment: That's a good point about ES5 vs ES6. I mostly do NodeJS, and they are good at incorporating ES6 as much as they can vs browsers.